# How do I solve this pip install web3 error?

Tags: python, windows, pip, web3py

I am attempting to install web3 in a python environment but keep getting met with the same error message in the terminal.

```
`PS C:\> pip install web3
Collecting web3
Using cached web3-6.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (568 kB)
Collecting aiohttp\>=3.7.4.post0
Using cached aiohttp-3.8.4-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (317 kB)
Collecting eth-abi\>=4.0.0-b.2
Using cached eth_abi-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting parsimonious==0.9.0
Using cached parsimonious-0.9.0.tar.gz (48 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting eth-account\>=0.8.0
Using cached eth_account-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (102 kB)
Collecting eth-hash\[pycryptodome\]\>=0.5.1
Using cached eth_hash-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.0 kB)
Collecting eth-typing\>=3.0.0
Using cached eth_typing-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.3 kB)
Collecting eth-utils\>=2.1.0
Using cached eth_utils-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting hexbytes\>=0.1.0
Using cached hexbytes-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting jsonschema\>=4.0.0
Using cached jsonschema-4.17.3-py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Collecting lru-dict\>=1.1.6
Using cached lru-dict-1.1.8.tar.gz (10 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting protobuf\>=4.21.6
Using cached protobuf-4.22.1-cp310-abi3-win_amd64.whl (420 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests\>=2.16.0 in c:\\python311\\lib\\site-packages (from web3) (2.28.2)
Collecting websockets\>=10.0.0
Using cached websockets-11.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (124 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32\>=223 in c:\\python311\\lib\\site-packages (from web3) (306)
Collecting regex\>=2022.3.15
Using cached regex-2023.3.23-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (267 kB)
Collecting attrs\>=17.3.0
Using cached attrs-22.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer\<4.0,\>=2.0 in c:\\python311\\lib\\site-packages (from aiohttp\>=3.7.4.post0-\>web3) (3.1.0)
Collecting multidict\<7.0,\>=4.5
Using cached multidict-6.0.4-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (28 kB)
Collecting async-timeout\<5.0,\>=4.0.0a3
Using cached async_timeout-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting yarl\<2.0,\>=1.0
Using cached yarl-1.8.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (55 kB)
Collecting frozenlist\>=1.1.1
Using cached frozenlist-1.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (32 kB)
Collecting aiosignal\>=1.1.2
Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting bitarray\<3,\>=2.4.0
Using cached bitarray-2.7.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (118 kB)
Collecting eth-keyfile\<0.7.0,\>=0.6.0
Using cached eth_keyfile-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting eth-keys\<0.5,\>=0.4.0
Using cached eth_keys-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting eth-rlp\<1,\>=0.3.0
Using cached eth_rlp-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Collecting rlp\<4,\>=1.0.0
Using cached rlp-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting pycryptodome\<4,\>=3.6.6
Using cached pycryptodome-3.17-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.7 MB)
Collecting cytoolz\>=0.10.1
Using cached cytoolz-0.12.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (315 kB)
Collecting pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,\>=0.14.0
Using cached pyrsistent-0.19.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (62 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna\<4,\>=2.5 in c:\\python311\\lib\\site-packages (from requests\>=2.16.0-\>web3) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3\<1.27,\>=1.21.1 in c:\\python311\\lib\\site-packages (from requests\>=2.16.0-\>web3) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi\>=2017.4.17 in c:\\python311\\lib\\site-packages (from requests\>=2.16.0-\>web3) (2022.12.7)
Collecting toolz\>=0.8.0
Using cached toolz-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
Installing collected packages: lru-dict, bitarray, websockets, toolz, regex, pyrsistent, pycryptodome, protobuf, multidict, hexbytes, frozenlist, eth-typing, eth-hash, attrs, async-timeout, yarl, parsimonious, jsonschema, cytoolz, aiosignal, eth-utils, aiohttp, rlp, eth-keys, eth-abi, eth-rlp, eth-keyfile, eth-account, web3
DEPRECATION: lru-dict is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
Running setup.py install for lru-dict ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for lru-dict did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[7 lines of output\]
running install
C:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\command\\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(
running build
running build_ext
building 'lru' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─\> lru-dict
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.`
```

I attempted "pip uninstall web3" so I could reinstall it but I was returned with:"WARNING: Skipping web3 as it is not installed."

I then attempt to install it again and am met with the error message above.

I ran pip install web3 and was hoping to install web 3 packages to use in python and was met with an error message. I have checked other questions but have not been successful in fixing the issue.

Comment: try to install another version by adding '==' after package
for example 'pip install requests==0.0.0.0'

Comment: Hi, i did manage to get it working I appreciate the help.